# Does anyone know how I can convert the time of my conworld into earth hours/days and vice versa? Is there a converter or formula I could use?

Tags: planets, alternate-worlds, time-keeping

I try to find out how long the years/days/hours in my conworld would be compared to those of Earth.
So here is some information about the conworld's time measures:

- 100 (earth)seconds = 1 (conworld)minute
- 40 (conworld)minutes = 1 (conworld)hour
- 48 (conworld)hours = 1 (conworld)day
- 70 (conworld)days = 1 (conworld)month
- 420 (conworld)days or 6 (conworld)months = 1 (conworld)year

I hope this is enough information to work with.

Comment: You've just given us the answer to your question in the question. This isn't a worldbuilding question so-much as one of arithmetic, which is not what we do here. Please take our [tour] and have a read of the [help]. Welcome to worldbuilding.

Comment: To be fair, there are many questions asked here that distil down to math. I'm guessing half to the questions that ultimately are answered by the square cubed law (the principle not the user who I think is great) are basic math like this.

Comment: I concur: this is a basic math problem. All you have to do is apply multiplication and division to convert from one system to the other. By the time you're done, you'll have a nice little conversion chart! I hope you'll understand that we're not going to actually do the maths or draw up the chart for you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an arithmetic problem solving question where the OP has done everything except the arithmetic to get the desired answers!

Answer (score 1):

You have told us that :

> 1Cm = 100Es

it follows then that:

```
1Cm = 1.67Em
```

This can be repeated substituted to give us:

```
1Ch = 40Cm = 40 * 1.67Em = 66.67Em = 1.11Eh
1Cd = 48Ch = 48 * 1.11Eh = 53.33Eh = 2.22Ed
1CM = 70Cd = 70 * 2.22Ed = 155.55Ed ~= 5.18EM
1Cy = 6CM ~= 6 * 5.18EM ~= 31.11EM ~= 2.59EY
```